# Initialization of MQQueueManager hangs in .NET core 2.2

Tags: c#, .net-core

We are having issues when initializing the Constructor for MQQueueManager. Our service is a Cron Job hosted on Kubernetes (AWS) which is scheduled to run every minute. This Cron Job connects to IBM MQ Server and reads the messages by looping through a list of queues. We are using "IBM MQ Client for .NET Core(9.2.0)" for connecting to MQ server.

Service was working fine for couple of months in Production , but one fine day the service stopped working, when checking the logs we could see Service was stuck while initializing MQQueueManager and Cron Job status in the POD was still showing running. Since the Cron Job was in running status , new jobs couldn't be created and finally we had to kill the POD on K8s to get the service up and running.

We have tried replicating the issue on our dev and test env's , but not succeeded yet. Not sure if the issue is while initializing
MQQueueManager constructor or the thread that is running is in deadlock. Below is the piece of code we are using... Any help would be appreciated....
Also there is no exception thrown...

```
private void InitialiseMQProperties()
        {
            try
            {
                _mqProperties = new Hashtable();
                _mqProperties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, _hostName);
                _mqProperties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, _port);
                _mqProperties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, _channelName);
                _mqProperties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);
                _mqProperties.Add(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, _userId);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Error("ConfigurationError: Initialising properties for Queue {Message}", ex.Message);
            }
        }

**This function gets called by the Cron Job every minute**

public async Task GetMessagesFromQueue()
        {
            try
            {
                InitialiseMQProperties();
                var queTaskList = new List<Task>();
                var _queues = _queueList.Split(',');
                foreach (var queue in _queues)
                {
                    queTaskList.Add(GetMessasgesByQueue(queue));
                }
                await Task.WhenAll(queTaskList).ConfigureAwait(false);
                Logger.Information("Messages successfully processed from the Queues");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Error("GeneralError: Reading messages from Queue error {Message}", ex.Message);
            }
        }

private async Task GetMessasgesByQueue(string queueName)
        {
            Logger.Information("Initialising queuemanager properties");
            var queueManager = new MQQueueManager("", _mqProperties);
            **From the logs it gets Stuck here**
            MQQueue queue = null;
            MQMessage message;
            MQGetMessageOptions getMessageOptions;

            try
            {
                getMessageOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions();
                getMessageOptions.Options |= MQC.MQGMO_SYNCPOINT + MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
                Logger.Information("Accessing queue {queueName}", queueName);
                queue = queueManager.AccessQueue(queueName, MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
                Logger.Information("Connection to queue succeeded");

                while (true)
                {
                    var commitTrans = true;
                    message = new MQMessage();
                    queue.Get(message, getMessageOptions);
                    var queMessage = message.ReadString(message.MessageLength);

                    Logger.Debug("Message read from MQ {0}", queMessage); //sensitive

                    if (queMessage.Length > 0)
                    {
                        var data = await _dataSerializer.DeserializePayload<Response>(queMessage);
                        if (data != null)
                        {
                           **Internal logic**
                        }
                    }
                            
            }
            catch (MQException mqe)
            {
                switch (mqe.ReasonCode)
                {
                    case MQC.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE:
                        Logger.Information("MQInfo: No message available in the queue {queueName}", queueName);
                        CloseQueue(queue);
                        break;

                    case MQC.MQRC_Q_MGR_QUIESCING:
                    case MQC.MQRC_Q_MGR_STOPPING:
                        CloseQueue(queue);
                        queueManager.Backout();
                        Logger.Error("MQError: Queue Manager Stopping error {Message}", mqe.Message);
                        break;

                    case MQC.MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_ACTIVE:
                    case MQC.MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE:
                        CloseQueue(queue);
                        queueManager.Backout();
                        Logger.Error("MQError: Queue Manager not available error {Message}", mqe.Message);
                        break;

                    default:
                        Logger.Error("MQError: Error reading queue {queueName} error {Message}", queueName, mqe.Message);
                        CloseQueue(queue);
                        queueManager.Backout();
                        break;
                }
            }
            Logger.Information("Closing queue {queueName}", queueName);
            CloseQueue(queue);
            CloseQueueManager(queueManager);
            Logger.Information("Closing Queue manager for queue {queueName}", queueName);
        }
```

Comment: Any help is appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar setup, I am using aks and XMS client for .net core 3.1,  running the CronJob every second, I saw a couple of crashes in Prod without understanding why even checking the POD logs, I had a conversation with the MQ team and their advice was to recycle the connection, it looks like the amount of connection exhaust the communication and crash the app but we couldn't see that in DEV or Test because of the amount of messages processed per environment.

What I ended doing was to spin up the container, create the connection with MQ and leave it open for the life cycle of the POD instead of each CronJob Cycle and destroying it only if the POD crashes or stops.

Something that worth evaluating?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. From my initial analysis, don't think it's issue with MQServer connection exhaust, reason being we had the recent prod issue , the pod was killed and all started working fine , but within couple of days we started facing the same issue.. Could be for some reason the threads are locking eachother and leading to deadlock not sure though. As a workaround we have changed the code to connect to only a single queue at a time rather than spinning off multiple threads...